# Manipulate Word Document

Tags: .net, vba, ms-word

We have a bunch of Microsoft Word Documents in which certain areas have a "Heading 2".  Is there any way via VBA or .NET code that we can open this document, find out where the "Heading 2" areas are and automatically change them to "Heading 3"?  It's very time consuming to do this manually and a programming solution would be nice.

Comment: Can I answer it with Python version?

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("YourOldStyle")
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("YourNewStyle")

    With Selection.Find

        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True

        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False

        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: That works great!  Thanks so much!  Do you happen to know the VBA to go to the top of the Word Document and then loop through this code so that all "Heading 2" will get changed to "Heading 3" ?  Fantastic!